# Rewriting of Formulas

Tags: z3

In [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/nbjorner/iwil08.pdf) (Section 3.2), it says that z3 applies rewriting/simplification of formulas before it does any other steps.

Suppose I have a formula in `QF_UF`, that consists of multiple `assert` statements. Is there any rewriting rule that would somehow "break the barrier" between different assert statements? Or, asking the other way round: Can I be sure that rewrite rules are only applied locally, "within" one assert statement?

For example, consider the following formula:

```
(set-logic QF_UF)
(set-option :auto-config false)
(set-option :PROOF_MODE  2)

(declare-fun a () Bool)
(assert a)
(assert (not a))

(check-sat)
(get-proof)
```

Can I be sure that the proof will contain a resolution step to prove `False`, or is it possible that `False` will be concluded by a rewrite/simplification step?

The reason I am asking is that for my application, every `assert` statement has a special semantics. Rewriting/Simplification across several `assert` statements would render the resulting proof of unsatisfiability unusable (or at least: very hard to use) for me.

Comment: Could you describe what are you trying to do? Why does rewriting/simplification across several asserts would make the results unusable? Note that, during search, Z3 will perform reasoning steps across several asserts. Would that also make the proofs unusable?

Comment: I am trying to rewrite the proof to a "pure" resolution proof. For application-specific reasons, simplifications and rewrites that occur inside one assert statement are of no interest to me. I.e., I will simply assume that the assert statement contained already the simplified version of the formula. All reasoning steps across assert statements are of interest to me and I have to deal with them somehow. If I could be sure that no simplification takes place across asserts, I have one (difficult) case less to deal with while I do my rewriting. I hope this makes it a little bit more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z3 3.2 applies several preprocessing steps. Using `(set-option :auto-config false)` will disable most of them. You should also include the following two options:

> (set-option :propagate-booleans false)
>
> (set-option :propagate-values false)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Will these options guarantee that no rewriting/simplification across assert statements will take place?

Comment: Yes, it will guarantee that in Z3 3.2.